# Load more products on click every time

Tags: php, mysql

currently i am displaying 4 products, want to add a button to display next 4 products , after another click next 4 products. how do i take value from $limit to display next 4 products from it.

```
<div class="row displaythumnail" >
                    <div class="product__list clearfix mt--30">
                            <?php
                            $get_product=get_product($con,4,'','','','','yes');
                            

                            foreach($get_product as $list){
                            ?>
                            <!-- Start Single Category -->
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="category">
                                    <div class="ht__cat__thumb">
                                        <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $list['id']?>">
                                            <img src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH.$list['image']?>" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" alt="product images">

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

function file code.
to Display next 4 product I think i have to take $limit value and next $limit-till. //like these
if( $limittil! = ' ')
{

```
            $sql.=" limit $limit, $limittil " ;
```

}
also add in parameter of get_product($con,$limit='',$limittil='',$cat_id='',$product_id='',$search_str='',$sort_order='',$is_best_seller='',$sub_categories='')  // like these,

but how to take previous limit that is $limit and next limit uptill that is $limitill , to display next 4 products

```
function     get_product($con,$limit='',$cat_id='',$product_id='',$search_str='',$sort_order='',$is_best_seller='',$sub_categories=''){
        $sql="select product.*,categories.categories from product,categories where product.status=1 ";
        if($cat_id!=''){
            $sql.=" and product.categories_id=$cat_id ";
        }
        if($product_id!=''){
            $sql.=" and product.id=$product_id ";
        }
        if($sub_categories!=''){
            $sql.=" and product.sub_categories_id=$sub_categories ";
        }
        if($is_best_seller!=''){
            $sql.=" and product.best_seller=1 ";
        }
        $sql.=" and product.categories_id=categories.id ";
        if($search_str!=''){
            $sql.=" and (product.name like '%$search_str%' or product.description like '%$search_str%') ";
        }
        if($sort_order!=''){
            $sql.=$sort_order;
        }else{
            $sql.=" order by product.id desc ";
        }
        if($limit!=''){
            $sql.=" limit $limit";
           
        }
    
        
    
        //echo $sql;
        $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $data=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $data[]=$row;
        }
    
    
        return $data;
    
    }
```

Comment: See about sql injection, and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Unless this is for academic purposes, you'd be much better served by using an existing system like [Magento](https://magento.com) or building on a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com). What you're doing here, smashing around with raw SQL, is both dangerous and unnecessary, any decent ORM will make this trivial and safe.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in prior post, SQL injection can be an issue.  Look at instead of:

```
$get_product=get_product($con,4,'','','','','yes');
```

Try using a 'filter_input' and trying something like this:

```
$get_product = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'con');
```

The filter_input will strip any harmful HTML code. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php for full details on that part.

When trying to us pagination for an SQL statement try something like this:

```
$paginationLimit = 'LIMIT '.$limit.', '.$limittil.'';
```

A great resource is by Paritosh Pandey at My Programming Tutorials (https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/create-pagination-with-php-and-mysql.html)